# ereg/eregi replacement for PHP 5.3

Tags: php, eregi, posix-ere

I'm sorry to ask a question but I am useless when it comes to understanding regex code.

In a php module that I didn't write is the following function

```
function isURL($url = NULL) {
    if($url==NULL) return false;

    $protocol = '(http://|https://)';
    $allowed = '([a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9]+)?)';

    $regex = "^". $protocol . // must include the protocol
                     '(' . $allowed . '{1,63}\.)+'. // 1 or several sub domains with a max of 63 chars
                     '[a-z]' . '{2,6}'; // followed by a TLD
    if(eregi($regex, $url)==true) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Can some kind soul give me the replacement code for that with whatever is required to replace the eregi

Comment: What is the purpose of replacing it?

Comment: @William, functions like `ereg`, `eregi`, `split` etc. are deprecated (not only deprecated, but completely removed) as of PHP 5.3. [Read more](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.posix.php).

Comment: Replacement altogether? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954064/ereg-eregi-replacement/9954148#9954148

Comment: @William, but this solution is too localized to this particular case... if he is porting some code to PHP 5.3, he needs more general solution.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Good question - this is needed when you upgrade to PHP 5.3, where `ereg` and `eregi` functions are deprecated. To replace

```
eregi('pattern', $string, $matches)
```

use

```
preg_match('/pattern/i', $string, $matches)
```

(the trailing `i` in the first argument means ignorecase and corresponds to the `i` in `eregi` - just skip in case of replacing `ereg` call).

But be aware of differences between the new and old patterns! [This page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.posix.php) lists the main differences, but for more complicated regular expressions you have to look in more detail at the differences between [POSIX regex](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.regex.php) (supported by the old ereg/eregi/split functions etc.) and the [PCRE](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php).

But in your example, you are just safe to replace the eregi call with:

```
if (preg_match("%{$regex}%i", $url))
    return true;
```

(note: the `%` is a delimiter; normally slash `/` is used. You have either to ensure that the delimiter is not in the regex or escape it. In your example slashes are part of the $regex so it is more convenient to use different character as delimiter.)

Comment: many thanks Tomas you are a star.

Comment: sorry Tomas your solution gives an error preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier 'h' is that being caused by the i after the }

Comment: @Colin, ok, I see! This is because the delimiter `|` is used in the $regex also... so we have to use different delimiter, which is not present in the $regex, e.g. `%` (hope I haven't overlooked something again :-)). Updated my answer.

Comment: many thanks that seems to have done the trick. One final question. eregi ignores case distinction when matching alphabetic characters. Does the code that I have now still do that or do I need to add anything more to what is in $allowed ?

Comment: @Colin, no, the ignorecase option is the trailing "i" you see at the end of the pattern parameter to `preg_match`. This new code should be completely equivalent to the old one.

Comment: thank you once again. I really appreciate the help you have given me and your explanations.

Comment: The [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eregi.php) says _(with the i (PCRE_CASELESS) modifier_ what does it mean ?

Answer (score 15):

Palliative PHP 5.3 until you replace all deprecated functions

```
if(!function_exists('ereg'))            { function ereg($pattern, $subject, &$matches = []) { return preg_match('/'.$pattern.'/', $subject, $matches); } }
if(!function_exists('eregi'))           { function eregi($pattern, $subject, &$matches = []) { return preg_match('/'.$pattern.'/i', $subject, $matches); } }
if(!function_exists('ereg_replace'))    { function ereg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string) { return preg_replace('/'.$pattern.'/', $replacement, $string); } }
if(!function_exists('eregi_replace'))   { function eregi_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string) { return preg_replace('/'.$pattern.'/i', $replacement, $string); } }
if(!function_exists('split'))           { function split($pattern, $subject, $limit = -1) { return preg_split('/'.$pattern.'/', $subject, $limit); } }
if(!function_exists('spliti'))          { function spliti($pattern, $subject, $limit = -1) { return preg_split('/'.$pattern.'/i', $subject, $limit); } }
```

Comment: Interestingly enough, the initialisation construct `&$matches = []` seems to fail under my particular version of PHP 5.3...

Answer (score 1):

Did you want a complete replacement to preg_match and eregi?

```
if(!filter_var($URI, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))
{ 
return false;
} else {
return true;
}
```

Or for Email:

```
if(!filter_var($EMAIL, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{ 
return false;
} else {
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`eregi` is depreciated in PHP you have to use `preg_match`

```
function isValidURL($url)
{
    return preg_match('%^((https?://)|(www\.))([a-z0-9-].?)+(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$%i', $url);
}


if(isValidURL("http://google.com"))
{
    echo "Good URL" ;
}
else
{
    echo "Bad Url" ;
}
```

Please see http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php for more information 
Thanks

:)

Comment: Your replacement regex does not apply the same rules

Comment: hey down voter .. do you care to give reasons why i was down voated ???

Comment: @meouw ...the rule is to verify valid email address ... am i missing anything

Comment: The question is about replacing the ereg regular expression with something equivalent - yours is not equivalent - yours has an optional protocol part, for example, wheras the original requires the protocol specifically

Comment: @meouw someone just gave a none regex example and did not get down voted ... All i gave is is a replacement for url validation .. I think you should have left Colin to decide if its relevant to him or now .. i don't have a wrong code ... it might not be 100% but that does not mean i should be down voted

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate your replies. My host has just upgraded to PHP/5.3.10 so the replacement is needed. The only thing I don't see in the solution provided by Baba is what the original function had of checking 1 or several sub domains with a max of 63 chars.

Comment: @Colin ... seen ... am happy we where able to help ....